# if else character logic is flawed

Tags: c++, c

Ok so I am now trying to check the code with the function below check_status().

Their are no errors in the code but I think I screwed up the logic. 
What i want to do when it runs is put in S and for it to print "CORRECT ANSWER. S"

Now the code works fine and prints out the error message when you put in FEFWRGV or something that isn't S, SH, MJ, MS. 
HOWEVER! when you put in SSDFIEWF or something of to that effect it says "CORRECT ANSWER. S"

The way i check to see if S was entered is 
if (status[0] == 'S')

Is there a way i can write a code like:
if (status[0] == 'S' && status[1] == void)

Because i know what i am doing is checking the status[0] and then i want to make sure that the status[1] isn't being used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>

//functions called
float wages_loop();
float other_loop();
float interest_loop();
void check_status();


//start main 
int main(void)
{
    char status[10], another[10];
    char buffer[80];

    float wages, other_income, interest, dividends, test;
    int dependents;
    int single_acc = 0, mj_acc = 0, ms_acc = 0, sh_acc = 0;

    printf("Would you like to start: ");
    gets_s(another);

    if (another[0] != 'y' && another[0] != 'n')
    {
        while (another[0] != 'y' && another[0] != 'n')
        {
            printf("\n\n INCORRCT ANSWER. \n\n");
            printf("\n Would you like to start. (y or n)");
            gets_s(another);
        }
    }
    while (another[0] == 'y')
    {


        check_status();


        interest = 0;


        printf("\n\n\t\t Your interest is: %.2f \n", interest);
        system("pause");

        printf("Would you like anoter: ");
        gets_s(another);

        if (another[0] != 'y' && another[0] != 'n')
        {
            while (another[0] != 'y' && another[0] != 'n')
            {
                printf("\n\n INCORRCT ANSWER. \n\n");
                printf("\n Would you like anoter. (y or n)");
                gets_s(another);
            }
        }

    } //end loop

    printf("\n\n\t\t\t Number of Singles filleing: %i \n", single_acc);

    return 0;

}//end main



void check_status()
{
    char status[10];
    int check = 0;

    while (check != 1)
    {
        printf("What is your Status: ");
        gets_s(status);

        if (status[0] == 'S' && status[1] == 'H')
        {
            printf("\n\n CORRECT ANSWER. SH \n\n");
            check = 1;
        }
        else if (status[0] == 'S')
        {
            printf("\n\n CORRECT  ANSWER. S \n\n");
            check = 1;
        }
        else if (status[0] == 'M' && status[1] == 'J')
        {
            printf("\n\n CORRECT ANSWER. MJ \n\n");
            check = 1;
        }
        else if (status[0] == 'M' && status[1] == 'S')
        {
            printf("\n\n CORRECT ANSWER. MS \n\n");
            check = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n\n INCORRECT ANSWER. noting \n\n");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your calls to [`gets_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b5x9wc7.aspx) is wrong. Does it even compile without errors?

Comment: As for your problem, you do know how all strings in C and C++ are terminated? It's even told in the reference I linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: Use `std::string` and compare: `if (my_string == "S") ....`

Comment: If this is C++, do not use character arrays. C++ has a nice string class called std::string. Use that. Everything else is is plain torture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way i can write a code like: if (status[0] == 'S' && status[1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg) == void)

You are nearly at it. The C-"string"-termination isn't `void` but `'\0'`.

So to test whether the "string" ends after the 1<sup>st</sup> character, that is `status[0]` do the following:

```
if (status[0] == 'S' && status[1] == '\0')
```

---

Btw: To declare a function without any arguments use `void`, like so:

```
check_status(void);
```

---

As [*Joachim Pileborg*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg) already commented on your question, you are using `gets_s()` incorrectly. [`gets_s()` takes **two** parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b5x9wc7.aspx).

The compiler should have warned you about this missing second parameter.

It is a good idea to take such warnings serious.